# Laravel 4 - Eloquent Group by relationship

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following relationship:

```
Company 
Reviews
```

These are linked through a link table `company_reviews`

What I want to do is select the most recent reviews but group it by the company_id. Is this possible using Eloquent or will I need to do this using raw SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation.
Something like this:

```
Reviews::select(review.*)   
->join('company_reviews', 'company_reviews.review_id', '=', 'review.id')
->join('company', 'company.id', '=', 'company_reviews.company_id')
->groupBy('company.id')
->get();
```